# strange editor behavior in local install of wordpress via mamp

Tags: php, mysql, macos, wordpress, mamp

I recently installed a local version of an in-progress wordpress.org blog on my Mac (10.7.5) and, though I followed the tutorial [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP), I cannot get the post or page edit views to display properly. I have tried reinstalling wordpress on my machine a few times, and then pulled the live version of the blog up to compare the editor stylesheet (my current guess as to the issue) with the local version and see no differences. I then spent most of the afternoon trying to see if anyone else has had this issue, and do not see mention of it on the wordpress.org forum or in MAMP's. I am on the latest version of wordpress, and have a fresh install of MAMP. Any ideas what I am overlooking? It looks like this no matter what i do:

[image]

Comment: Yep, it is in the /Applications/MAMP/htdocs with the rest of the wordpress files.

Comment: Did u install wordpress in a folder?If so its not showing in url

Comment: I mean it must be localhost/foldername/wp-admin/

Comment: Oh, hm. Okay. The doc I was following did not mention that, though that would make sense. Wordpress lives in a folder at `/Users/MYUSERNAME/sites/wordpress/`. How ought I to be typing that into the browser?

Comment: so it should be `localhost:8888/Users/MYUSERNAME/sites/wordpress/wp-admin`, for example?

Comment: i havent used MAMP.But I think sites is the root folder.Try localhost:888/wordpress/

Comment: System Requirements for latest wordpress installation
PHP version 5.2.4 or higher.
MySQL version 5.0 or higher.

Comment: Okay, tried this: `http://localhost:8888/wp-admin/post.php?post=1&action=edit`, and I still get the same results. This results in a 404: `http://localhost:8888/username/sites/wordpress/wp-admin/`, as does this `http://localhost:8888/Users/username/sites/wordpress/wp-admin/`.

Comment: I am definitely on PHP v5.4.4. No idea how to check the MySQL version, though.

Comment: how is the site front end shown?Check mysql version in phpmyadmin

Comment: MySQL version 5.5.25, so that should be fine. I can get to the front end simply from here `http://localhost:8888/`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If u have installed wordpress correctly refferring  [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress_Locally_on_Your_Mac_With_MAMP).Try these solutions [link](http://wordpress.org/search/dash+board+not+displayed+properly?forums=1)

Comment: Thanks for that, @Arunu. I found documentation of this issue, and a few solutions, [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/mamp-no-wp-dashboard-css) from relatively recently (not sure how I missed that discussion earlier). I think Chrome cached the site. When I cleared all of my browser data it was fixed, likely from one of the times I reinstalled WP (seems others have had the same issue).